# An efficient method for server side data streaming?

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, streaming, audio-streaming

Is there an efficient way of streaming data from client side to server side for typical web applications? For example, I want to take audio/video/media input from the clients and deliver these inputs to the servers to process the data. To accelerate the processing of data, it is clear that we should use data streaming strategy. Any suggestions / solutions? ( Javascript preferred. ) The solution should be adaptable to J2EE platforms.

Comment: Generally you can either use HTML5 media APIs or rely on a flash bridge. Are HTML5 Technologies acceptable?

Comment: I don't know whether HTML5 is supported by many browsers or how much time is required for HTML5 to be standard worldwide. So I prefer a way which will be "platform independent".

Comment: then you need to find a flash based media uploader. There might be a solution that uses HTML5/JavaScript where possible and has a flash fallback.

Comment: Your question is about browser side streaming. Please change the title of the question.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for an interactive streaming solution, let me explain, the data should be sent to the server via streaming so that the engines can start to process the streaming data as soon as streaming data starts to arrive. it's not related with streaming data to the clients. ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Red5: http://www.red5.org/